# Session Id is changing every request in ASP.NET core 2.1 web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on asp.net core web application. I am not much aware of session state. When i login the application i have got the session id and I have pushed some user data's into session using HttpContext.Session. That values are under current sessionid. And then i sent that sessionid to client(browser). where i having using angularjs.

Whenever i sent the request after login. i have sending the sessionid along with request in request header. But after request reached my backend(WebApi) where i have seen another sessionid in HttpContext.Session. but i have my sessionid which that having those session values. But using current HttpContext.Session's sessionid couldn't get those session values.

Whether i have to get those session values by my sessionid which was came along request header or have to change HttpContext.Session's sessionid or Won't allow to change HttpContext.Session's sessionid for every request. Everything i have mentioned is have tried but couldn't do anything.What else is there? Please someone help me!. I could seen lot of answers about it in online but everything is for .Net Framework not for ASP.Net core 2.1.

Here is my code,

I have set session values in my user controller. and after login i will fill data in my quote creation page and give submit. Meanwhile i have to get my session values(which i stored in user controller login method) in my quote controller create method. So current request sessionid is changed in Httpcontext(even i use IHttpContextAccessor).so couldn't get my session values

```
    public class UserController : Controller {
public string Login(User objUser)
{... 
HttpContext.Session.SetString("CompanyId", "1");
...}
```

}

```
public class QuoteController : Controller {
public string CreateQuote([FromBody]Quote objQuote)
{... 
var companyId = HttpContext.Session.GetString("CompanyId");
...}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This should help. You can access season
by **HttpContext**.

Check this example how work with seasson string.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

public class HomeController : Controller {
    public IActionResult Index()
    { 
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", "Testing Session.");
    return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
    ViewBag.Message = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Test");

    return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Laci R for responded to my post. I had tried both the way you mentioned above, but nothing worked for me. So I wanted to show my code so I have altered my question from previous post please look on it and please give another solution